# MVC - Website crashes when browsing after sitting idle for 20 minutes, gives "The system cannot find the file specified error."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, nlog

I have been wrecking my head regarding an error I keep getting in my **ASP.NET MVC** and **EF 6 project**. It is part of a large solution (18 projects) and only my project seems to be encountering an issue.

We use **Ninject** for Dependency Injection and all my settings match the other projects exactly. However, when viewing my site through HTTPS after sitting idle for 20 minutes when I go to navigate to another section within my application it spins, then crashes and shows an error

> The system cannot find the file specified.

It goes on to also show a `SqlException` with error code 52. I can't find where this error is occurring. If I don't use HTTPS when viewing my site, it loads instantly and never has any problems.

I have error handling with logging added to all my controllers and yet this error is not logged. Instead, the only place I see this error is in Event Viewer and on the webpage.

It uses **Forms Authentication**, and has no session expiration time just like all the other sites. What I find weird is, if I refresh the home page (in another project) it fixes the issue. The home page utilizes a project that handles our authentication, role assignments, and so forth. It does utilize access to the same database. It uses `database-first` as its EF approach, as do the other projects.

Things I have done:

- Converted my database-first context into a code-first with existing database
- Changed the App Pool timeout to 100 (I doubt this was the problem since all other projects are fine and use the same App Pool)

Things different:

- Only my project uses `NLog`, the other projects have a different logging utility

Would `NLog` be causing this issue? It is the only thing that seems to stick out, but I am not sure.

Is there any tools that can help my trace what kind of connection my site is trying to make when it gets that error?

Provided below is a bit of detail on the exception:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file >specified]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
> error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
> server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
> name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
> connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to
> locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server
> Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime
> feature is enabled.)]

Provided below is my Ninject configuration:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(R.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(R.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]
    namespace R.App_Start
   {
    using System;
    using System.Web;
    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;
    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;
    using Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost;
    using R.Service;
    using R.Interface;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IZRepository>().To<ZRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<ICRepository>().To<CRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<IERepository>().To<ERepository>();
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: 20 minutes is the default session timeout for ASP.Net MVC. Perhaps when a session is expired information is lost about how to connect to the database?

Comment: I considered that, and changed the timeout to 100 minutes, but it still happens. The other apps don't suffer this problem, either before or after the timeout change.

Comment: Is NLog configured to log to a database target? If not, I don't see how it could cause that issue.

Comment: It is configured to a database target.

Comment: Configure it to a different target for testing purposes. If it no longer crashes, NLog is using incorrect database connection string.

Comment: It isn't using an incorrect database string because I do see errors being logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the cookie timeout was set to exactly 20 minutes, changing the cookie timeout resolved the issue.